# Mark/tag video sections

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

Is there a way or a script that allows you to load a video and lets the user viewing the video mark certain sections of the video as 'interesting' for example, and then link directly to these sections (not start time, but sort of a combination of start+end time)?

Comment: “JavaScript”? There is a video API…

Comment: @minitec can you please elaborate? How can I use js to mark video sections and then link back to these sections? I googled it but couldn't find any useful information.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? There are various sections you can break this down into. I’d start at looking up how to set the current position in the video programmatically.